# JSP includes and MVC pattern

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, servlets

I am new to JSP/Servlets/MVC and am writing a JSP page (using Servlets and MVC pattern) that displays information about recipies, and want the ability for users to "comment" on it too.

So for the Servlet, on doGet(), it grabs all the required info into a Model POJO and forwards the request on to a JSP View for rendering. That is working just fine.

I'd like the "comment" part to be a separate JSP, so on the RecipeView.jsp I can use  to separate these views out. So I've made that, but am now a little stuck. The form in the CommentOnRecipe.jsp posts to a CommentAction servlet that handles the recording of the comment just fine. So when I reload the Recipe page, I can see the comment I just made.

I'd like to:

- Reload the page automatically after commenting (no AJAX for now)
- Block the user from making more than one comment on each Recipe over a 1 day timeframe (via a Cookie). So I store a cookie indicating the product ID whenever the user makes a comment, so we can check this later? How would it work in a MVC context?
- Show a message to the user that they have already commented on the Recipe when they visit one
  which they have commented on

I'm confused about using beans/including JSPs etc on how to achieve this.

I know in ASP.NET land, it would be a UseControl that I would place on a page, or in ASP.NET MVC, it would be a PartialView of some sort. I'm just confused with the way this works in a JSP/Servlets/MVC context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use response.sendRedirect() or forward APIs in javax.servlet to redirect to a new page or refresh the same page (redirect to the same page/path so that the beans/data gets refreshed)

about restricting to one comment per day - yes you can use cookie but the problem is that user might use another browser type (chrome, FF, Safari) and will be able to make multiple comments.
Ideally you should store the lastCommentTime in the model/persistent store and tie it to the user information - this way your model object can expose an API that checks the last comment time and returns true/false depending on whether user can comment or not.
You can use this API in your servlet/JSP to show/hide the comment button, for example and also show a message

Comment: Thanks... I thought about the Cookie thing, that's a good point. Users aren't required to register on the site, it's all relatively anonymous, so I can't tie specific recipes/comments to user ids. So, in light of this, my Model class (which is called Recipe) should expose functionality to check if a user has already voted on it? I shouldn't use a Service class to do this? E.g. RecipeService.HasVoted(recipeId) which then checks if a cookie is set?

Comment: unlikely. So the entity objects (Recipe in this case) typically dont have too much business logic sitting in them. The service layer which uses the entity objects is a good place to put such logic. so in effect your MVC looks like: Entity/POJO model objects->Service Objects->Servlets/viewmodel/viewHelpers->View/JSP/HTML and thats certainly a good MVC architecture. So RecipeService.userHasVoted(userid) is a good place to put it - contd...

Comment: The only issue is that since this state is being stored in the View in some sense due to your functionality limitations - it becomes moot to ask the service when you are actually storing it in a cookie :) I wil not advice your service layer to check the cookie. Rather, let the servlet check the cookie and invoke an API on the service layer to set the state (and then use another API to read the state) - this will help keep your service layer clean so down the line if you support storing user information, it becomes easy to change